# Facing problem while converting string DateTime to Date only in Ms Access

Tags: date

Question:
I have two datetime fields which I have imported as string using CSV import in ms-access.
However now in access these string datetime, I want only date and that is in short date format.

Following are the two fields in string format in ms-access table imported using CSV

Start Date: 1/12/2022 8:36
End Date: 1/13/2022 3:25

However, when I use DateValue() function to get the date part from each of the above two fields the "Start Date" format automatically set to mm/dd/yyyy, while the "End Date" field format sets to dd/mm/yyyy.

Now, when I calculate the difference in the two dates one is appearing as (1/12/2022 = 01-Dec-2022) and other is appearing as (1/13/2022 = 13-Jan-2022), which is resulting in wrong calculation of the difference of dates.

I have used formatdate(), CDate(), DateValue() and other function as well. However, no gain achieved. The surprise is that the datetime as string in ms-access is showing same in both the fields, but when I convert them to DateValue() the format get changed automatically.

Seeking a prompt reply.

Regards,
Faisal

Answer (score 0):

Difference in two dates can be calculated using the expression below

=CDate([enddatestring])-CDate([startdatestring])
// the above expression will convert the date value from string to date

The format of the calculated control field should be general number

i have attached two images that demos it.

[image: Form view]

[image: Form design view]

Comment: I tried the solution you proposed but still getting same dates.
The Start Date is 01/12/2022 converting automatically to 01-Dec-2022, although it should convert to 12-Jan-2022 (as in 2022 we are still in Feb-2022)

Comment: Ok, so the final thing to alter is to go to your Windows control panel, Regional and Language, Pick format tab, under format drop down-Pick  English United states, then under short date-pick M/d/yyyy,  under long date- pick  MMMM  dd,yyyy.  Then save your settings by clicking ok. After that you go and Close and re-open access again.